# Dotnet core webapi requiring Azure b2c authorization sending error which cannot be consumed by Android Volley

Tags: android-volley, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Volley to connect to a dot net core web api protected by Azure B2C. The issue is that I am getting back a HTML response from the API making it hard to identify and resolve on the in the client app.

The response I am getting back is:
[image]

HTML behind it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><title>Logging in...</title><meta name='CACHE-CONTROL' content='NO-CACHE'/><meta name='PRAGMA' content='NO-CACHE'/><meta name='EXPIRES' content='-1'/></head><body><form id='auto' method='post' action='https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc'><div><input type='hidden' name='error' id='error' value='redirect_uri_mismatch'/><input type='hidden' name='error_description' id='error_description' value='AADB2C90006: The redirect URI &#39;https://dev.webapi.enablewear.com/signin-oidc&#39; provided in the request is not registered for the client id &#39;[guid here]&#39;.
    Correlation ID: [guid here]
    Timestamp: 2021-02-19 13:28:34Z
    '/><input type='hidden' name='state' id='state' value='[token here]'/></div><div id='noJavascript' style='visibility: visible; font-family: Verdana'><p>Although we have detected that you have Javascript disabled, you will be able to use the site as normal.</p><p>As part of the authentication process this page may be displayed several times. Please use the continue button below.</p><input type='submit' value='Continue' /></div><script type='text/javascript'>
                        <!-- 
                            document.getElementById('noJavascript').innerHTML = ''; document.getElementById('auto').submit(); 
                        //--></script></form></body></html>
```

The only way I can get that information is through a Volley StringRequest:

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.toString());
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            //param.put(IndicationDM.NAME, indication.getName());
            return param;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
            Log.d(TAG, "getHeaders: Bearer " + accessToken);
            header.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            return header;
        }

    };
```

I would rather use a JsonObjectRequest and handle errors like this:

```
            if ( error instanceof AuthFailureError ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: AuthFailureError");
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: NetworkError");
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: ParseError");
            }
```

but the problem is that the AuthFailureError is not being called, the ParseError is because the HTML above is not JSON. I wish the result came back as json or kicked off the AuthFailureError, but I'm not sure if there is a webapi configuration I need to change or Azure b2c configuration.

The dotnet core webapi controller is using the [Authorize] attribute. I may need to refresh the token, but I will run into this issue and want to catch/respond to it.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I looked at [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C/TodoListService) and made changes to the startup.cs and am now getting the AuthFailureError, which is great. I still am finding it incredibly hard to diagnose challenges, which is the subject for a different post. Here is what I changed:

**TO:**

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => 
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            },
            options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });


        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddAuthorization();
```

**FROM:**

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
```

I cannot say for sure I did not change anything else. I was trying to make tweaks on the server, but this was actually the last change I remember making/testing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "protected by B2C" here means that it is deployed to an [Azure Web App service using Easy Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) is still the case. Once you configure an app service to require authentication, it will expect to either get an access token in the authorization header or an authorization cookie in the request. App Service does not distinguish between hosting an API or a Web App (html). If it does not get an access token or a cookie it will presume that a browser is trying to access a web app and initiate OIDC redirect to the server. Your client calling the API should treat a 302 response as unauthorized. Your Web Api should not use [Authorize] or attempt to validate incoming tokens. The Azure service will do that. You can retrieve the claims (and the token) in your app code using either environment variables or the ClaimsPrincipal as per the article.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't consider this. Many of the examples I have been reading have used [Authorize]. I was looking at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C/TodoListService and made some changes in the startup and am now getting an AuthFailureError. Will there be impact as I try to I turn towards more fine grained scopes. Also I am having real trouble diagnosing problems. It's great I'm getting the error but nothing shows up in the logs.

Comment: Correction: you can have [Authorize] - it does nothing since all request have to authorized when using Easy Auth. You must NOT use any token handling in Startup though since that is handled by Azure Web App service itself.